# JavaScriptのテストですべての分岐をPASSしているのにカバレッジが100%にならない

Tags: javascript, テスト, 非同期, jestjs

下図（図1）のソースコードを3つのテストメソッドからなるテストスイートでカバレッジを取ったところ図1のように漏れがありました。1番目のテストケースを単体で実行してもカバレッジは図1のようになります。

**図1: カバレッジに漏れがあるソースコード**

[image: 図1 カバレッジに漏れがあるソースコード]

しかし、2番目のテストケースを単体で実行するとカバレッジは下図（図2）のようになります。

**図2: 2番目のテストケース単体でのカバレッジ**

[image: 図2 2番目のテストケース単体でのカバレッジ]

また、テストケース3を単体で実行すると下図（図3）のようになります。

**図3: 3番目のテストケース単体でのカバレッジ**

[image: 図3 3番目のテストケース単体でのカバレッジ]

これらの図の結果を合わせると網羅率が100%になると思うのですが、npm testコマンドを実行して3つのテストをいっぺんに走らせても図1のようなカバレッジになり、100%にはなりません。100％にするための解決策を教えてください。
JestもJavaScriptもあまり慣れていないので、うっかりミスもあるかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

ソースコード（js\callbackQuestion.js）

```
   import { handleErrors } from './fetchErrHandler.js'

export default async function innerCallback(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const yearfield = document.getElementById('id_year')
    const monthfield = document.getElementById('id_month')
    const url = '/year/month/';
    const csrfmiddlewaretoken = "HueNL6M9N0bQhj02V64dj7LudpKICZhQR8vrSuBP1aMe25";
    var data = { year: yearfield.value, month: monthfield.value }
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfmiddlewaretoken
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).catch(e => {
            throw new Error(e);
        });
        handleErrors(response);
        let json = response.json();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error:' + e);
    }
}
```

js\fetchErrHandler.js

```
    export const handleErrors = res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      switch (res.status) {
        case 400:
          throw Error ('INVALID_TOKEN');
        case 401:
          throw Error ('UNAUTHORIZED');
        case 500:
          throw Error ('INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR');
        case 502:
          throw Error ('BAD_GATEWAY');
        case 404:
          throw Error ('NOT_FOUND');
        default:
          throw Error ('UNHANDLED_ERROR');
      }
    }
    else {  // res.ok == true
      return res;
    }
};
```

テストファイル（js\ __tests__\coverageQuestions.test.js）

```
import innerCallbackFunction from "../callbackQuestion";

describe("click event", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // レンダリングされたstaffs.htmlを読み込む
        const fs = require("fs");
        document.body.innerHTML 
            = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../staffs.html", {
                    encoding: "utf-8",
                });
    });
    it("[test 1] should pass with 200", async () => {
        // fetch のモックへ渡すデータを決める
        const dataElement = document.getElementById("id_data");
        const data = {
            status_code: 200, 
        }
        dataElement.value = JSON.stringify(data);

        //  fetchのモックの実装定義
        const windowFetch = require("../__mocks__/fetchTargetMonth");
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(windowFetch);

        const innerCallback = innerCallbackFunction;

        // create an Event
        let changeMonthBtn = document.getElementById('id_change_month_btn');
        const event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent("click", true, false);    
        changeMonthBtn.dispatchEvent(event);

        expect.assertions(2);
        // イベントリスナーの登録＆実行
        await expect(innerCallback(event)).resolves.toBeUndefined();
        expect(fetch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
    it("[test 2] fail inside the callback func. because no status code", async () => {
        // fetch のモックへ渡すデータを決める
        const dataElement = document.getElementById("id_data");
        const data = "";  // data が無いとfetchモックでエラーになる。
        dataElement.value = JSON.stringify(data);

        //  fetchのモックの実装定義
        const windowFetch = require("../__mocks__/fetchTargetMonth");
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(windowFetch);

        const innerCallback = innerCallbackFunction;

        // create an Event
        const changeMonthBtn = document.getElementById('id_change_month_btn');
        const event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent("click", true, false);    
        changeMonthBtn.dispatchEvent(event);

        expect.assertions(2);
        // innerCallback 内では例外を投げるが、ここに戻るのは Promise
        await expect(innerCallback(event)).resolves.toBeUndefined();
        expect(fetch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it("[test 3] throw error with 400 inside the callback cought in the outer catch", async () => {
        // fetch のモックへ渡すデータを決める
        const dataElement = document.getElementById("id_data");
        const data = {
            status_code: 400, 
        }
        dataElement.value = JSON.stringify(data);

        //  fetchのモックの実装定義
        const windowFetch = require("../__mocks__/fetchTargetMonth");
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(windowFetch);

        const innerCallback = innerCallbackFunction;

        // create an Event
        const changeMonthBtn = document.getElementById('id_change_month_btn');
        const event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent("click", true, false);    
        changeMonthBtn.dispatchEvent(event);

        expect.assertions(2);
        // innerCallback 内では例外を投げるが、ここに戻るのは Promise
        await expect(innerCallback(event)).resolves.toBeUndefined();
        expect(fetch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

fetchのモックファイル（js\ __mocks__\fetchTargetMonth.js）

```
    // DOMの一部を借りてデータの受け渡しをする
const dataElement = document.getElementById("id_data");
const response = JSON.parse(dataElement.value);

const windowFetch = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if ( !response ) {
            throw Error('テストコードに response データを指定してください！');
        }
        if (response.status_code == 200) {
            resolve({
                ok: true, 
                status: response.status_code, 
                json:  () => ((response))
            });
        } else {
            resolve({
                ok: false,      // resolveするが、status.ok は false
                status: response.status_code, 
                json:  () => ((response))
            });
        }
    });
};
module.exports = windowFetch;
```

staffs.html（関連する要素以外省略）

```
    <input type="number" name="year" value="2021" min="2000" style="width:70px;" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="" disabled="" id="id_year"> 年 <input type="number" name="month" value="7" style="width:50px;" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="" disabled="" id="id_month"> 月
<input id="id_change_month_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control-sm" type="hidden" value="変更">
・・・略・・・
<input type="hidden" id="id_data" value="">
```

以上です。足りない情報などありましたら、コメントください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いろいろ試しているうちに解決方法を発見しました。
下記コードのようにbeforeEachの冒頭に「jest.resetModules();」を一行挿入するだけで、カバレッジが100％になりました。
詳細なしくみまでは分かりませんが、連続でテストする際に、モジュールのキャッシュが使われて、前と同じ変数の値が使われていたようです。

```
beforeEach(() => {

    jest.resetModules();

    // レンダリングされたstaffs.htmlを読み込む
    const fs = require("fs");
    document.body.innerHTML 
        = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../staffs.html", {
                encoding: "utf-8",
            });
});
```

お騒がせしました。

※追記：他のテストをやっていて、jest.resetModules();だけでは100％にならない場合もありました。公式APIドキュメントを見て、下記のコマンドで一度キャッシュを削除してから、もう一度「npm test」を実行するとカバレッジが100%になりました。

```
> npm test -- --clearCache
```